# regex in preg_replace does not replace across multiple lines

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

The following preg_replace checks a line beginning with a `*`, and puts html tags around it. This works well, the only problem with this is, it'll work only if there is one line supplied to it and not if there's more than one.

I've tried adding `\s` and `m` to it, but nothing will get it to work. What can be done to get this working?

```
$str = <<< EOF
*Portfolio
Our work includes...
*Company Profile
Acme was formed in 
EOF;

$str = preg_replace('/^\*([^\*].*)$/', '<h1>$1</h1>', $str);

echo $str;

//Expected output
<h1>Portfolio</h1>
Our work includes...
<h1>Company Profile</h1>
Acme was formed in

//Current output either works if there's only one line.
```

Comment: show some examples for multiple lines.

Comment: Without multiline flag `/m` the `^` anchor just matches at the start of the subject string, not at the start of lines.

Comment: Tangential: `[^\*]` looks wrong, was `[^*]` intended instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `m` (multi-line) modifier to do this.

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?m)^\*([^*].*)$/', '<h1>$1</h1>', $str);
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lZ1hQ9/6)

Comment: Ok. Just out of curiosity, that change in between the regex was done for...

Comment: A small problem. Rows beginning with more than one * should not be matched. See updated demo `http://regex101.com/r/lZ1hQ9/3`. Which is why that thing was in there in between (which you changed) :)

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/lZ1hQ9/4

Comment: @jmenezes It is fixed.